# android timer handler

Tags: android, android-handler

I am using this code:

```
public class newtimer extends Activity {

    private Timer myTimer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TimerMethod();
            }

        }, 0, 1000);
    }

    int number = 0;

    private void TimerMethod()
    {
        //This method is called directly by the timer
        //and runs in the same thread as the timer.

        //We call the method that will work with the UI
        //through the runOnUiThread method.

        Toast.makeText(this, "TimerMethod Running "+number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
    }

    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            //This method runs in the same thread as the UI.
            //Do something to the UI thread here

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "UI Thread Running "+number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };
}
```

When i run it i get this exception in logcat:

> 09-06 21:39:39.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1433): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: That code was completely misformatted. Please look at the preview before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the problem is with the `Toast.makeText(this, "TimerMethod Running "+number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` in your TimerMethod function - you can't call any functions pertaining to the UI from worker threads. Since you already have a Toast in the portion that runs in the UI thread, why do you have another one in TimerMethod?

For debugging, I would recommend using Log as much as possible instead of Toast.